# How to allow SSH over PPP?

Tags: ssh, networking, ppp, pppd

I have these two computers connected through ppp.

One has ip `10.10.0.1` and the other has ip `10.10.0.2`.

Both also have the interface `ppp0` with netmask `255.255.255.255`:

```
# ifconfig
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.0.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 7  bytes 105 (105.0 B)
        RX errors 3  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1522 (1.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How can I make it possible to connect from `10.10.0.2` into `10.10.0.1` using SSH?

If I make:

```
# ssh -vv root@10.10.0.1
```

I can see that it gets frozen at:

```
.
.
.
password: 
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 10.10.0.1 ([10.10.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

Watching everything from tcpdump I see this:

```
# tcpdump -i ppp0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
22:15:48.592651 IP tlcmelo > 10.100.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17288, seq 1, length 64
22:15:48.942907 IP 10.100.0.1 > tlcmelo: ICMP echo reply, id 17288, seq 1, length 64
22:15:49.593728 IP tlcmelo > 10.100.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17288, seq 2, length 64
22:15:49.821594 IP 10.100.0.1 > tlcmelo: ICMP echo reply, id 17288, seq 2, length 64
22:15:50.595483 IP tlcmelo > 10.100.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17288, seq 3, length 64
22:15:50.840112 IP 10.100.0.1 > tlcmelo: ICMP echo reply, id 17288, seq 3, length 64
22:15:51.597014 IP tlcmelo > 10.100.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17288, seq 4, length 64
22:16:00.105020 IP tlcmelo.57621 > 10.100.0.1.57621: UDP, length 44
22:16:38.104153 IP tlcmelo.57621 > 10.100.0.1.57621: UDP, length 44
22:17:04.490191 IP tlcmelo.37489 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
22:17:05.490773 IP tlcmelo.37489 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
22:17:06.491775 IP tlcmelo.37489 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
22:17:07.492280 IP tlcmelo.37489 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
22:17:16.104112 IP tlcmelo.57621 > 10.100.0.1.57621: UDP, length 44
22:17:54.103994 IP tlcmelo.57621 > 10.100.0.1.57621: UDP, length 44
22:18:32.105034 IP tlcmelo.57621 > 10.100.0.1.57621: UDP, length 44
```

---

Edit 1:

@derobert, thanks for your message: It is not possible also to ssh from `10.10.0.1` back to `10.10.0.2`, same issue actually. I tried a smaller MTU, no success unfortunately.

@pizdelect, thanks for your message: I am running debian in both computers. I tried setting MTU to 1000 and 500, no success yet.

Edit 2:

In the `10.10.0.1`, doing `iptables -vL` I see these:

```
Chain Block (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   75  3210 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere            !0.0.0.255/-1         limit: avg 3/hour burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "Iptables: Block: "
    6   360 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
 2433  143K REJECT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Is that possible that it is blocking the connection?

Comment: It should just work. Does ssh to localhost (from 10.10.0.1) work? That'd at least demonstrate the ssh server is working.

Comment: what are you running ppp over? try setting the mtu and mru to a lower value. also, what system is that? openbsd?

Comment: @derobert a mtu = 1500 will certainly not "just work" with pppoe. icmp echos and small packets will get through though ;-)

Comment: @pizdelect Well, OP's tcpdump doesn't even show *any* ssh traffic, but the debug output shows session established and authenticated. So something is weird. Besides, PPP should figure out the right MTU for PPPoE.

Comment: I don't know whether ppp "should" figure out the right mtu for pppoe, but it usually doesn't -- take for instance the (vanilla) openwrt on my router, where 1492 it is passed as a parameter to pppd (and it also does mss clamping via iptables).

Comment: @derobert thanks for your answer, it is not possible to ssh in the other direction as well, I tried MTU = 1000 and 500, no success yet

Comment: @pizdelect thanks for your message, I tried smaller values for MTU, but no success

Comment: So either `ssh`/`sshd` has trouble, or the ppp-connection has trouble. You can test the first by doing `ssh root@localhost` on both machines. You can test the second by using something else besides `ssh` which uses large packets, e.g. `iperf`, or netcat/socat with a suitable payload, or even `ping` with a custom size.

Comment: Yes, ssh is working on both. I also tried other TCP connections, netcat, ... actually, only ping works.

Comment: Do you have firewall rules set up (check with `iptables -vL`)? If you vary the size of the pings (with `ping -s SIZE`), are only small pings able to get through? Up to 1472 should work with a 1500 MTU. And can you give any details about the PPP connection? Is this a RS232 (or similar) serial port, are there modems involved, or is this something else like PPPoE or a PPP-based VPN?

Comment: @derobert thanks again for your answer. Weird thing is, even `ping -s 1500 10.10.0.1` works. Actually, `iptables -vL` in the `10.10.0.1` is insane, I think the problem is there, definitely it is, thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: You will need to allow the ssh through the firewall. Did you came across the following documentation? [https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/ppp-ssh.pdf](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/ppp-ssh.pdf)